# Combining dataframes correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, data-science

I have 3 dataframes I need joined horizontally. There are no common columns to enable me tie them together. I have tried merge, join, concat. Maybe I did something wrong while coding.

This is the data frame1:

```
grill_type  is_frozen   item_material
0   Propane false   Hotdog
0   Propane true    Hotdog
0   Propane true    Hotdog
0   Propane false   Hotdog
0   Propane true    Hotdog
```

This is the data frame2:

```
guess_grill_correct thumbs_up_score
0   true    0.4
0   true    1.0
0   true    0.0
0   true    0.0
0   true    0.4
```

This is the data frame3:

```
sample_item_index
0   1
0   10
0   10
0   11
0   12
```

As you can see, three dataframes are all without indices.

I want to have something like this:

```
sample_item_index   item_material   is_frozen   grill_type  thumbs_up_score guess_grill_correct
0   1   Veggie Patty    False   Propane 0.0 True
1   1   Hotdog          False   Propane 0.4 True
2   2   Veggie Patty    True    Propane 0.9 True
3   3   Veggie Patty    False   Propane 0.8 True
4   4   Veggie Patty    True    Propane 0.8 True
```

When I try to use merge like for example:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='index', how = 'left')
```

The result will be mutiple extra rolls which is not what I want

Any suggestion is wellcome!

Comment: The input and output don't make sense. Where did Veggie Patty come from in the output?  Where did some of the numbers from thumbs_up_score come from? Kindly make the output producible from the input -- not data that is excluded from your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you seem to want to concat. There is no other way to achieve what you want. Please try

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)
```

Comment: @Leo, if it is working, feel free to accept the answer. I can help edit your question